# Прерывается соединение на putty

Tags: putty

Через *putty* подключаюсь к удаленному серверу (*Ubuntu*). Если не "трогать" *putty*, то соединение разрывается, причем, пока не трогаю, никаких признаков разъединения нет, а как только попытаюсь ввести какую-нибудь команду, то всплывает окно, что соединение разорвано. Проблема возникает если я долго не работаю на *putty*. Использую интернет *3G*. Через обычный, выделенный интернет *putty* нормально работает. Грешу на провайдера, но *аська* ведь не разъединяется периодически.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попробуйте поиграться с вот этими настройками:

[image: Putty settings]

Comment: Вроде помогает... через некоторое время будт ясно...